# SpringBoot and Ajax responses

Tags: java, ajax, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm starting a new project with SpringBoot, Spring MVC and Thymeleaf. I want to do a very simple thing, but I don't know which is the best approach with these frameworks. I'm new to Thymeleaf too.

In a view, I want to load a select with a list of Java objects from the server. Then, when I change this select I want to update a form with the values of each Java object, so the user can edit it. In a nutshell, I have to load on demand every single object, binding its values, then send the new values to the server if the user saves these changes.

How can I do this?

Comment: with thymeleaf you can use fragments and ajax, so you would have a controller when receive the select changes and update a div in your main page with the form data of that particular object.

Comment: @cralfaro do you have any link I could check with code examples?

Comment: @jpadillladev you could have a look here http://www.marcelustrojahn.com/2016/08/spring-boot-thymeleaf-fragments-via-ajax/

Comment: @cralfaro I will take a look, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although this answer is mainly opinion ed based. But it should get you started. I would start with 2 controllers, one to handle all your Thymeleaf page requests. These are what handles going to a different page or landing page. The second controller to handle all the Ajax requests coming from the user interaction on the page (selecting a new list, and save changes) . For that use your favorite javascript library.

Comment: I think the answer by cralfaro is a bit more specific because I use thymeleaf in my project. But I will try this approach too, thanks.